# Why is my Stack empty? EmptyStackException

Tags: java, stack

I'm working with Stacks in Java at the moment.
The problem I'm facing is that I want to create a Stack which stores items of the type "candy".
I want to add that "candy" at the Producer.java
But when I run the code shown below I get the error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.EmptyStackException
>
> at java.util.Stack.peek(Stack.java:102)
>
> at java.util.Stack.pop(Stack.java:84)
>
> at app.fachinformatiker.myMashup.Model.Consumer.(Consumer.java:10)
>
> at app.fachinformatiker.myMashup.Main.Main.initializeConsumers(Main.java:84)
>
> at app.fachinformatiker.myMashup.Main.Main.main(Main.java:42)

These are the corresponding lines

Consumer.java:10

```
String Candy = candyStack.pop();
```

Main.java:84

```
consumerList.add(new Consumer(candyStack));
```

Main.java:42

```
 initializeConsumers();
```

I don't get it why my stack isn't properly filled.

Below you will find some snippets of my code.
If you want to download my whole code and run it in an IDE of your choice (I use IntelliJ IDEA), here's a direct link to the archive on GitHub (specific commit) : https://github.com/fachinformatiker/myMashup/archive/97e3ffb.zip

Here's some snippets of my code:

In my Main.java

```
private static final Stack<String> candyStack = new Stack<>();
private static final ArrayList<Producer> producerList = new ArrayList<>();
private static final ArrayList<Consumer> consumerList = new ArrayList<>();

...

private static void startProducers() {
    for (int i = 0; i < producerList.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println("I would start producer Nr. " + i + " now.");
        producerList.get(i).start();
    }
}

private static void startConsumer() {
    for (int i = 0; i < consumerList.size(); i++) {
        Debug.gebeInfoAus("I would start consumer Nr. " + i + " now.");
        consumerList.get(i).start();
    }
}

private static void initializeProducers() {
    if (ArgController.istAusgewertet) {
        Debug.gebeInfoAus("Producer istAusgewertet");
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < ArgController.getAnzahlProduzenten(); i++) {
        Debug.gebeInfoAus("Producer Nr. " + i + " added to candyStack");
        producerList.add(new Producer(candyStack, i));
    }
}
```

in my Producer.java

```
public class Producer {

    private Candy candy = new Candy();
    private String myCandy;

    int hell = candy.getHell();
    String hope = candy.getHope();

    public Producer(Stack<String> candyStack, int i) {
        myCandy = i + ";" + hell + ";" + hope;
        candyStack.push(myCandy);
        Debug.gebeInfoAus(myCandy);
    }

    public void start() {

    }
}
```

In my Consumer.java

```
public class Consumer {

    public Consumer(Stack<String> candyStack) {
        String Candy = candyStack.pop();
        Debug.gebeInfoAus(Candy);
    }

    public void start() {

    }
}
```

Comment: "If you want to download my whole code and run it in an IDE of your choice ..." - No.  Sorry.  That's not the way StackOverflow works.  If you want help debugging your code, you need to provide an MCVE **in the question itself**.  One of many reasons is that the link to your repo is liable to break (e.g. because you deleted it) removing the context for your question, and making it less helpful for future readers.  You may not care about that, but the stated goal of SackOverflow is to build a collection of Q&As that are useful to everyone.

Comment: The short answer is that the stack appears to be empty.  Either your app has made more `pop()` calls than `push(...)` calls, or there are multiple threads updating a shared data structure (e.g. the `Stack` instance) without synchronizing properly.  The later could lead to all sorts of odd behavior, including apparent loss of things from the stack.